# Is it consistent that the gaps between cardinals $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$ "get larger and larger"?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Is the following statement consistent in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

> > For every ordinal $\beta$ there is an ordinal $\lambda_0$ such that for all ordinals $\lambda\geq\lambda_0$ we have $2^{\aleph_{\lambda}}\geq \aleph_{\lambda+\beta}.$

Comment: Easton's theorem will give you the answer, methinks

Comment: @DavidRoberts Will it? The question includes those $\lambda$ for which $\aleph_\lambda$ is singular, and unlike regular cardinals, those are not an easy matter to control. I seem to remember a past question on the consistency of $(\forall\lambda)\,2^{\aleph_\lambda}=\aleph_{\lambda+2}$, and while I can't remember the conclusion, I think it wasn't at all trivial.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Of course it will give the answer. Even if you only apply Easton's theorem to the class of successors of limits of cofinality $\omega$, it will still suffice to ensure the gaps are arbitrarily large.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you notice how Dominic had asked his question, he inquires not just that there are arbitrarily large gaps, but that the gaps become *eventually* as large as desired, and so this would include singular cardinals. So I think we really need the sophisticated tools of the Foreman-Woodin model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the Foreman-Woodin model for the global failure of $GCH$ your statement is true.

See [The generalized continuum hypothesis can fail everywhere.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2944324?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: Thanks for this link! So if I understand it correctly, as a special case, given an ordinal $\beta$, it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0} \geq \aleph_\beta$? Is it also possible that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{2^{\aleph_0}}$? (The answer to the latter is perhaps "No", for some simple reason that escapes me at the moment.)

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Now *this*, unlike your original question, is reducible to Easton's theorem, which is a much easier result than Foreman-Woodin. Basically, you can make $2^{\aleph_0}$ equal to whatever $\kappa$ you like provided only that it has uncountable cofinality. (In particular, of $\kappa$ is the smallest fixed point of uncountable cofinality of $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$, you can make $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$.)